# SQL Procedure - Begin Transaction & Commit

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Hi i am writing a procedure "pro_reallocate_block" inside that,
i am calling another Procedure "pro_remove_allocation". if i put  BEGIN TRANSACTION   for the main procedure "pro_reallocate_block", in case of any error occurrence in main procedure will it revert the sub Procedure "pro_remove_allocation".

```
Create procedure pro_reallocate_block(
@blockId int,
@blockName nvarchar(max)
)    
WITH EXECUTE AS CALLER      
AS      
Begin           

 SET XACT_ABORT, NOCOUNT ON;        
 BEGIN TRY          
 SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE        
 BEGIN TRANSACTION        

Declare @AllocatedBlockid int

 exec pro_remove_allocation @blockId 
 if((select COUNT(blockId) from blocks where blockId=@blockId)>0)
    select * from blocks where blockId=@blockId 
    else 
        select * from blocks where bdefault=1
 COMMIT TRANSACTION        
 SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED        
 END TRY        

 BEGIN CATCH        
  IF XACT_STATE() <> 0        
  BEGIN        
   ROLLBACK TRANSACTION        

   DECLARE @ErrorMessage NVARCHAR(4000);        
   DECLARE @ErrorSeverity INT;        
   DECLARE @ErrorState INT;        

   SELECT @ErrorMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE(),        
       @ErrorSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY(),        
       @ErrorState = ERROR_STATE();        

   RAISERROR (@ErrorMessage, @ErrorSeverity, @ErrorState);        
  END        
 END CATCH    
end
```

Comment: It should do, AFAIK. Perhaps the best thing to do is write some test procs and raise an error to see if the rollback works. Then you will know for sure.

Comment: Please don't `COUNT()` when all you want to do is check for existence. That's what `EXISTS` is for. If you're lucky, the optimizer will spot your intent and transform it to the equivalent `EXISTS` form, but why force it to do more work?

Comment: Damien_The_Unbeliever Thankyou for your suggestion... How came about Transactions!